# Uploading Android library to Bintray - userOrg parameter is ignored

Tags: maven, gradle, bintray, jcenter

I am trying to upload an Android library to Bintray using this guide:
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

Everything works fine until I try to run bintrayUpload, when I get the following error:

Execution failed for task ':MAS:bintrayUpload'.

> Could not create package 'user/maven/my-repo': HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [message:Repo 'maven' was not found]

I think the problem is that the repository is owned by the organisation on Bintray. But it's looking for it under the user. 
ie. user/maven/my-repo should be organisation/maven/my-repo.

My local.properties looks like this:

```
...    
bintray.userOrg=organisation
bintray.user=user
bintray.apikey=key
bintray.gpg.password=password
...
```

My build.gradle for the library module looks like this:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2016 CA. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software may be modified and distributed under the terms
 * of the MIT license.  See the LICENSE file for details.
 *
 */

//noinspection GradleCompatible
// In order to build messaging using gradle 2 environment variables must be exportedd
// 1. prefix - this is the aar prefix, for example 'android'
// 2. versionName - this is the v.r.m formatted version name as used in the AndroidManifest.xml.
// For example, 1.1.0

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.7"
    id "com.github.dcendents.android-maven" version "1.5"
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'



ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'mobile-app-services'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.ca'
    libraryName = 'MobileAppServices'
    artifact = 'mobile-app-services'

    libraryDescription = 'The Android Mobile SDK gives developers simple and secure access to the services of CA Mobile API Gateway and CA Mobile App Services. '

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/CAAPIM/Android-MAS-SDK'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/CAAPIM/Android-MAS-SDK.git'

    libraryVersion = '3.2.00'

    developerId = 'devId'
    developerName = 'Full Name'
    developerEmail = 'user@email.com'

    licenseName = 'The MIT License (MIT)'
    licenseUrl = 'license.com'
    allLicenses = ["MIT"]
}

println '------> Executing mas library build.gradle'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.2"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    println "Source: $source"
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    println "Classpath: $source"
    options.memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PROTECTED
    destinationDir = file("../docs/mas_javadoc/")
    failOnError false

    include '**/*MAS*.java'
    include '**/Device.java'
    include '**/ScimUser.java'

    exclude '**/MASTransformable.java'
    exclude '**/MASResultReceiver.java'
    exclude '**/MASWebServiceClient.java'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile project(':MAG')
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When uploading context to a Repository that is owned by an Organization, you have to comply with the Bintray REST API convention by using the following path:  **OrganizationName/RepoName** and not **UserName/RepoName**.

I do not know what is the using of the 'maven' word in the path you wrote above.

For the case you have above the following Bintray REST API links can be helpful:

- [create new Package](https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_create_package)
- [upload maven content](https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_maven_upload)
- [upload any content](https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_upload_content)

In the situation above The **:subject** refers to the Organization name (and not the Username). In any case that the Repository is under the user the **:subject** is referred to the Username.

For more details please follow the full [Bintray REST API documentation](https://bintray.com/docs/api/).

Another way to upload your file is by using the [Bintray UI](https://bintray.com) which can be much more visible to understand the structure of your Repositories, Packages, Versions and Artifacts.